# Websocket connection fail in .net 4.6

Tags: websocket, signalr, .net-4.6

I have a signalr that worked nice with 4.5
After upgraded to 4.6 it works ok on Win 2008 R2 , but does not work on Windows 2012 .

The error is :

```
System.InvalidOperationException: WebSockets is unsupported in the current application configuration. To enable this, set the following configuration switch in Web.config:
system.web
httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" 
system.web
For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=252465.
at  
System.Web.Util.SynchronizationContextUtil.ValidateMode(SynchronizationContextMode currentMode, SynchronizationContextMode requiredMode, String specificErrorMessage)

at System.Web.HttpContext.AcceptWebSocketRequest(Func2 userFunc, AspNetWebSocketOptions options) at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Transports.WebSocketTransport.AcceptWebSocketRequest(Func2 callback)
at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.PersistentConnection.ProcessRequestPostGroupRead(HostContext context, String groupsToken)
at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.TaskAsyncHelper.FromMethodT1,T2,T3,TResult
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Owin.Mapping.MapMiddleware.d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at 

    Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.StageAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult ar)
    at         System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
    at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

If I add  httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" to web.config , the application won't run at all.

Comment: Is your problem resolved?

Answer (score 8):

Adding

```
 <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
```

To web.config solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are hosting your server in IIS you need to enable websockets in IIS. Here are the details: http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-websocket-protocol-support

Comment: Yes, I am hosting the server in IIS.  And WebSocket is enabled.